# What is the correct drive caddy for this 2012 era Dell Optiplex 580?

Tags: hard-drive, dell-optiplex

I am refurbishing a 2012 era Dell Optiplex 580 which has had its drive caddy removed. What is the correct caddy for this model? I am having trouble verifying the part, since Dell has reused the name "Optiplex 580" over the years.

I already have the 5.25" DVD drive that sits on top; this only requires the special screws. What is missing is the caddy that sits beneath it, that doubles as the mounting point for the 3.5" bay in the front.

I also think that I might need these special screws that Dell uses, which don't always come with a caddy replacement.

Can someone confirm the correct caddy I need with a photo and verify whether I need any kind of special screw?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-580_service%20manual2_en-us.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the manual as well as the correct drive caddy. The part numbers are 0XJ418 and 0D7579, according to eBay listings.

Here is a link to he correct manual as well:

https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-580_service%20manual_en-us.pdf

Apparently, the name "Optiplex 580" is used for three sizes, differentiated by the suffix "Desktop", "SFF", "Mini Tower".

[image]

[image]

You do not need a caddy to mount a device that has access to the front panel.Instead, it mounts with three of Dell's special screws that are typically used on their optical drives (see the photo in my question for a picture of the screw head).

[image]

Comment: Yes most Dell models come in a variety of sizes. This is not exclusive to Dell, HP does this, & I'm guessing Lenovo does as well

Answer (score 1):

https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-580_service%20manual2_en-us.pdf

Dell.com/support might be able to put in your service tag, then go to specs to get part numbers. Haven't had a ton of luck with that in the past. I'd probably just search eBay & match picture to repair manual I linked above. Also these guys have always had the right part # matching OEM. Been servicing Dell for 9yr now: https://www.parts-people.com/index.php?action=item&id=23336

Comment: I did find that manual in my own search, but the layout and parts for not match mine, so I am uncertain whether the caddy will fit. The power supply, for example, is completely different, and the layout in those photos is nothing like the inside of mine.

Comment: The first stock picture you supplied was of a SFF: Small Form Factor so that is the one I selected to get info on, I guess I should have compared it to the second picture which appears to be of a MT: Micro Tower. Please consider up voting my answer if it helped you find the info you needed

Comment: I did attach the wrong stock photo, which I've corrected. I have also upvoted your answer, since the suggestion to try searching Dell's website using the service tag was helpful in locating the answer.